# matching records in awk by reverse order

Tags: unix, awk

This is the piece of code  i am using to extract certain rec from "my_file":

```
awk '/Exception/ && !/ExceptionUnparseable date/ {
       haveEx="yes"; ex=$0; **exDate=last**}
     haveEx && /tms/ {
       print exDate; print ex; haveEx=""}
     {last = $0} ' my_file
```

my requirement is . exDate=last -> this part of my  code is supposed to store the record which comesjust prev to my match . but unfortunately some times the requirement is to check many records prev to the match.

So in short I need to match the "last" record to a "regular expression" \^[0-9][0-]*\ if its not matching then i need to move one more record backwards ,  like until my reg - exp matches. if its matched i need to store that record in the variable "exDate" as mentioned above.

what i have done so far is to try to put a if condition inside the awk, but not sure how to track back more and more until the  req matches.

Comment: You only want to store as "last" a record that matches a given regular expression? So only so the `{last = $0}` action when your record matches that expression, no?

Comment: am not able to get what you said. but i can explain my requirement with an example. also i have not added the regular expression code here in the question.  last is a awk variable which fetches the previous record to the match .

if there is a  match "/Exception/ && !/ExceptionUnparseable date/" then it will fetch the previous line which is suposed to be a date. 
in some cases its a date , in some cases the line which is previous to the previous of match is the date. in some cases its even more before. in short i need to  go back until to check the previous record of my match is a date

Comment: Right, you are storing the previous line in `last`. *Every* line gets stored. You don't want every line to get stored though. You only want *matching* lines to get stored. So instead of having an unconditional `{last = $0}` action use your regex pattern as the pattern for that action and only store lines that match your regex. `/^[0-9][0-]*/ {last = $0}`

Comment: i am trying wil definitely get back in few mins. reallythanks for you help first  of all.

Comment: it works perfectly fine. thanks a ton!! but what ever. there are two things.
1. need to  learn a lot in awk , still confused , any recommendations ?
2. i need to contribute more to this forum i really dont want to only take but need to give back

Comment: start with http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . Then get the modern awk book, "Effective Awk Programming", by Robbins. Good luck.

Comment: just stored the same link yesterday. will get that book too. right away..thank a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can store the date pattern independent of the other pattern match and print once that pattern is satisfied.  This way you don't need to search back.  If I understood your problem correctly this should work

```
$ awk '/^[0-9-]*$/{lastDate=$0} 
        /pattern1/{exDate=lastDate; lastDate=""} 
 pattern2/&&exDate{print exDate}' << EOF
> asdf
> asdf
> 2015-11-20
> asdfa
> pattern1
> asdfa
> asdfa
> pattern2
> asdf
> asdf
> EOF
2015-11-20
```

Comment: thanks a lot karafa . this is was the answer even fedorqui said.thanks again for taking your time.